# Is it possible to install 32 bit container in 64 bit host, or the other ways?

Tags: docker, operating-system, 32bit-64bit, host, raspberry-pi4

I’m try to use picamera, raspistill on raspberry pi.
I recognized that these modules are Only work in 32bit os.
But I want to use another development that works in 64bit os.

So my question is this.
Is it possible to make or install container that is different from host os?

1. Host: 32bit, Container: 64bit

- I think docker officially support 64bit os. so this will be not... right?

2. Host: 64bit, Container: 32bit

- If it will be OK. Can I mix my local 64bit function and Container 32bit function?

Answer (score 1):

There is a feature to run multiple architectures on the same kernel. I use this to run i386 binaries in an amd64 container on an amd64 host OS/kernel.

Debian call this [Multiarch](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch). I haven't tried this on arm, but in theory this could work the same as on Intel.

Look at the [Multiarch HOWTO](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO):

1. use a base container for an architecture in your Dockerfile, e.g. `image=debian:buster-slim`
2. add another architecture: `dpkg --add-architecture armhf`
3. update package list: `apt-get update`
4. install the tools and libraries for the respective architecture (e.g. armhf or arm64): `apt-get install -y yourpackage:armhf`

As I said I only used that for i386, there might be more pitfalls with arm.

/edit: I use the same now also for a ARM64 Linux running armhf binaries (32 bit) in a docker container.

Comment: Thank you for answer! What about running 64bit container on 32 bit host?!

Comment: This 32 bit kernel with 64 bit user space will not work, but the other way round works. I'm now using an RasPi4 with ARM64 Linux kernel and ARM64 docker to run an ARM64 container which also contains some armhf (32-bit) binaries and libraries via the multiarch feature.